# Problem with contexts

Tags: contexts

Starting a fresh kernel and writing the following set of commands:

Define a new context `temp` and a variable name `x` in it.

```
temp`x=2;
```

Next define a global variable with the same name.

```
x=1;
```

Next I run the following commands sequentially and separately so that parser does not use the same context throughout.

```
Begin["temp`"];

Print[{x, Global`x, temp`x}];

End[];
```

I get `{1, 1, 2}` but was expecting `{2, 1, 2}`.

If I look at `$ContextPath`, `temp` doesn't exist in it.

Comment: Look at the documentation of `$ContextPath`: "...is a global variable that gives a list of contexts to search, before $Context, in trying to find a symbol that has been entered.".

Comment: When I begin `temp` then shouldn't `x` correspond to temp\`x not Global\`x.

Comment: What can I say? :) The namespace system of Mathematica is confusing and one of the worst you will ever see in *today's* languages. It's why Wolfram puts all new functions directly into the ``System` `` namespace, because no sane user understands how to work with contexts. Fact is, you can get a pretty decent understanding of how everything works by reading the documentation of `Begin`, `BeginPackage`, `$Context`, and `$ContextPath`. You will remember this for the rest of ... the next few days. Then you look it up again. Sorry, but unfortunately, that's how it is.

Comment: I think linked topic should answer everything except why those decisions were made. Let me know if you disagree with closing.